# Allow IP to access to phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp, config

I have installed wamp on a computer and I use it as a local server

I would like to allow access to the phpmyadmin to an ip (in addition to the local) in order to access the database from my PC

So I opened the `phpmyadmin.conf` file (`c:/wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf`)

It looks like this :

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

And I add `Require ip 10.25.xx.xx` after the line `Require local`

I rebooted wamp but it does not work .. I have add and delete other line without success

How I can do ? Thank you

EDIT : It looks like this :

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride all
      <IfDefine APACHE24>
        Require local
        Require ip 10.25.269.56
      </IfDefine>
      <IfDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
          Deny from all
          Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
        </IfDefine>
      php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
      php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
      php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
      php_admin_value max_input_time 360
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Show what you have actually done, as it sounds like it should have worked, so it must be a simple mistake

Comment: ps: you dont need to obfiscate a 10.25.x.x address, they are all local only ip addresses and cannot be addressed from outside your local network. But if you actually used `10.25.xx.xx` that wont work

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you, I have edit the post but my code don't work ...

Comment: And you are sure that the Other PC you are trying to connect to WAMPServer FROM is ip address `10.25.269.56`